# Show results from 2 queries

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL queries like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
   COUNT(kodeall) AS Total, kodeall, kode, LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
FROM
   dbo.data 
WHERE 
   date BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00'
   AND (kodeall IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY 
   kodeall, kode 
ORDER BY 
   kode1
```

and results

```
Total  l kodeall l kode l kode1 
2        1a         AA     1     
5        1d         BB     1           
2        2a         CC     2           
6        2d         DD     2           
1        2e         EE     2           
3        3a         FF     3           
2        3c         GG     3           
1        3f         WW     3
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT     
    COUNT(kodeall) AS Sum, LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
From 
    dbo.data 
WHERE 
     date BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' 
     AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00' 
     AND (kodeall IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY 
     LEFT(kodeall, 1)
```

and results

```
Sum l kode1 l 
 7      1     
 9      2     
 6      3
```

and if i want show results like this

```
Total  l kodeall l kode l kode1 l sum l Percentage
2        1a         AA     1       7     28.57 %
5        1d         BB     1       7     71.43 %
2        2a         CC     2       9     22.22 %
6        2d         DD     2       9     66.66 %
1        2e         EE     2       9     11.11 %
3        3a         FF     3       6     50 %
2        3c         GG     3       6     33.33 %
1        3f         WW     3       6     16.67 %
```

sum is count kodeall by kode1 in query A.

and percentage = Total / sum *100
example 2/7*100

please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of the messy `<br>` tags, either!

Comment: i'm sory.thx your information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yourself already get pretty close to answer. I use SQL Server as RDBMS as example. You didn't mention RDBMS in your question. 
I use two CTE(common table expression) to save your two queries, then join them together and calculate percentage, please note, you percentage in final result actually is a string.

```
;WITH CTE_TotalKodeall
AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
       COUNT(kodeall) AS Total, kodeall, kode, LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
    FROM
       dbo.data 
    WHERE 
       date BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00'
       AND (kodeall IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY 
       kodeall, kode 
    ORDER BY 
       kode1
), CTE_SUMKodeall
AS 
(
   SELECT     
    COUNT(kodeall) AS [Sum], LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
   From 
    dbo.data 
   WHERE 
     date BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' 
     AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00' 
     AND (kodeall IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY 
     LEFT(kodeall, 1)  
)
SELECT A.Total, A.kodeall, A.kode, A.kode1, B.[sum], 
       LEFT(cast((A.Total/(B.[SUM]*1.0) *100.0) as varchar(30)),5)+'%' as Percentage
FROM CTE_TotalKodeall A 
JOIN CTE_SUMKodeall B
ON A.kode1 = B.kode1
```

Comment: how set percentage with decimal 2 digit

Comment: Do you mean you just want to show 74% instead of 74.13%? If so, you need to use ROUND() function, like following:LEFT((CAST(ROUND((2/(7*1.0)*100.0),0) AS VARCHAR(30))),2)+'%'

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    COUNT(kodeall) AS Total,
kodeall, kode, 
LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1 ,
    sum1,
    ((Count(kodeall)/sum1 )* 100) As percentage
FROM
   dbo.data 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT     
    COUNT(kodeall) AS Sum, 
LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
    From 
    dbo.data 
   WHERE 
      date BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' 
      AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00' 
      AND (kodeall IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY 
     LEFT(kodeall, 1)  
  ) temp on temp.kode1 = dbo.data.kode1 

WHERE 
   date BETWEEN '2013/03/01 00:00:00' AND '2013/03/01 23:59:00'
   AND (kodeall IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY 
   kodeall, kode 
 ORDER BY 
   dbo.data.kode1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty close (untested)

```
With cte1 as (
    SELECT COUNT(kodeall) AS Total, kodeall, kode, LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
    FROM dbo.data 
    WHERE date >= '2013/03/01' AND  date < '2013/03/02'
       AND kodeall IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY kodeall, kode 
), cte2 as (
    SELECT COUNT(kodeall) AS Sum, LEFT(kodeall, 1) AS kode1
    From dbo.data 
    WHERE date >= '2013/03/01' AND  date < '2013/03/02'
       AND kodeall IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY LEFT(kodeall, 1)
)
SELECT c1.Total, c1.kodeall, c1.kode, c1.kode1, 
    c2.sum, c1.Total/c2.sum percentage
FROM cte1 c1 
    JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.kode1 = c2.kode1
```

Be careful using `BETWEEN`, especially for date fields.  I'd use greater than or less than instead.

Comment: @rian -- those are just aliases -- makes it easier than typing the entire table/cte name out.  you can use aliases with columns and tables :)